# How to make a half-sheet flyer to be cut apart?

Tags: memoir, flyers

I want to make flyers that are 8.5'' * 5.5'' in size (i.e., half of a US letter sheet of paper), which I can cut apart and hand out. So I did this:

```
\documentclass[landscape,60pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{tabular}{cc}

        \begin{minipage}[c]{12cm}

            \begin{vplace}[0.7]
            \centering
            \HUGE

            THIS IS\\AN\\IMPORTANT\\MESSAGE
            \end{vplace}
        \end{minipage}

        &

        \begin{minipage}[c]{4.5in}

        \begin{vplace}[0.7]
            \centering
            \HUGE

            THIS IS\\AN\\IMPORTANT\\MESSAGE
        \end{vplace}
        \end{minipage}

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image: test image]

Right now there are a couple of issues:

- The columns are not centered horizontally on the page (which I tried to do with the uniform margin)
- The type should be nearly centered on the page (which I tried to do with `\vplace`)

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues with your document:

- The `minipage`s didn't have the same width. I adjusted them, so their sum is less then the paper width.
- `minipage`s automatically take the height of their content, so the `vplace` environment in there doesn't do anything.
- You forgot to remove the parindnet (done here with `\noindent`).
- The margin moved both columns to the center, thus they wouldn't be the same after cutting. Fixed here by setting the margin to 0.

The centering is done here with a few `\hfill`s. Note that there are two between the `minipage`s. Also, I removed the spurious spaces produced by the new line after `\end{minipage}` by commenting them out.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,60pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{vplace}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{4in}
    \centering
    \HUGE
     THIS IS\\AN\\IMPORTANT\\MESSAGE
\end{minipage}% <-- important, remove the space
\hfill\hfill
\begin{minipage}{4in}
    \centering
    \HUGE
    THIS IS\\AN\\IMPORTANT\\MESSAGE
\end{minipage}% <-- important, remove the space
\hfill
\end{vplace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tangentially, how did you get that frame around the result?

Comment: @crmdgn it's just a frame drawn by the PDF viewer and its background, used to make the screenshot. There is no frame in the document.